# Python - counting nucleotides

Tags: python, bioinformatics

So I am supposed to devise a program that counts a DNA sequence as well as count the individual base pairs. Here's what I have thus far:

```
class dnaString (str): 
    def __new__(self,s): 
        return str.__new__(self,s.upper()) 
    def length (self): 
        return (len(self)) 
    def getATCG (self,num_A,num_T,num_C,num_G): 
        num_A = self.count("A") 
        num_T = self.count("T") 
        num_C = self.count ("C") 
        num_G = self.count ("G") 
        return ( (self.length(), num_A, num_T, num_G, num_C) ) 

    def printnum_A (self): 
        print ("Adenine base content: {0}".format(self.count("A"))) 

dna = input("Enter a dna sequence: ") 
x=dnaString(dna)
```

The program doesn't really do anything, and since I'm just starting out with python, I'm not sure how to fix this so it works. what else should I add? I know it's unfinished.

Comment: which error are  you getting? are you using python3, aren't you?

Comment: Declaring a `length` method is redundant - `str` already implements `__len__`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the question, but as you are not calling the method ´printnum_A`, nothing is printing. If  you call it like this, it works:

```
dna = input("Enter a dna sequence: ") 
x=dnaString(dna) 
x.printnum_A()
```

---

**Update according to comments**

It is not enough to declare the methods of a class, you need also to call then when you need them. Like here for `printnum_T`:

```
class dnaString (str): 
    def __new__(self,s): 
        return str.__new__(self,s.upper()) 
    def length (self): 
        return (len(self)) 
    def getATCG (self,num_A,num_T,num_C,num_G): 
        num_A = self.count("A") 
        num_T = self.count("T") 
        num_C = self.count ("C") 
        num_G = self.count ("G") 
        return ( (self.length(), num_A, num_T, num_G, num_C) ) 

    def printnum_A (self): 
        print ("Adenine base content: {0}".format(self.count("A"))) 

    # here the method is declared
    def printnum_T (self): 
        print ("Adenine base content: {0}".format(self.count("T")))

dna = input("Enter a dna sequence: ") 
x=dnaString(dna) 
x.printnum_A()
# Here I call my method on `x`
x.printnum_T()
```

Comment: thanks, that works. I proceeded to also list "x.printnum_T, x.printnum_G, etc." after "X.printnum_A" to see if I can also get the numbers of those bases. however, that doesn't seem to work. how come?

Comment: you have to declare the method in your class definition and the call them. I will edit my answer with an example for `printnum_T`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? It works in Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.3 that I happen to have installed.

```
import itertools
import sys

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
        return zip(a,b)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

class DnaSequence():
    Names = {
        'A' : 'adenine',
        'C' : 'cytosine',
        'G' : 'guanine',
        'T' : 'thymine'
    }
    Bases = Names.keys()


    def __init__(self, seq):
        self._string = seq
        self.bases = { x:0 for x in DnaSequence.Bases }
        self.pairs = { x+y:0 for x in DnaSequence.Bases 
                             for y in DnaSequence.Bases }

        for base in seq:
            if base in self.bases:
                self.bases[base] += 1

        for x,y in pairwise(seq):
            pair = x+y
            if pair in self.pairs:
                self.pairs[pair] += 1


    def printCount(self, base):
        if base in DnaSequence.Names:
            print(DnaSequence.Names[base].capitalize() + 
                  " base content: " + str(self.bases[base]))
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('No such base ("%s")\n' % base)


    def __repr__(self):
        return self._string


d = DnaSequence("CCTAGTGTTAGCTAGTCTAGGGAT")
for base in DnaSequence.Bases:
    d.printCount(base)

# Further:
print(d)
print(d.bases)
print(d.pairs)
```

It's a complete example that counts the bases (A, C, G, T) and all occurrences of adjacent pairs (e.g. in ACCGTA, the pairs AC, CC, CG, GT, TA would all be 1, the other 11 possible combinations of the Cartesian product ACGT x ACGT would all be 0).

The counting method used here scans the string once in the constructor, rather than scanning it four times every time `getATGC()` is called.

Comment: this should be added as a class method

Comment: @RubenBermudez: I changed it a little :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the class can be simplified a bit:

```
class DnaString(str): 
    def __new__(self, s): 
        return str.__new__(self, s.strip().upper())

    def __init__(self, _):
        self.num_A = self.count("A") 
        self.num_C = self.count("C") 
        self.num_G = self.count("G") 
        self.num_T = self.count("T") 

    def stats(self):
        return len(self), self.num_A, self.num_C, self.num_G, self.num_T
```

then

```
dna = raw_input("Enter a dna sequence: ") 
d = DnaString(dna)

print(d)
print(d.stats())
```

gives

```
Enter a dna sequence: ACGTACGTA
ACGTACGTA
(9, 3, 2, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using a dictionary to organize and retrieve your counts. For instance:

```
    DNASeq = raw_input("Enter a DNA sequence: ")

    SeqLength = len(DNASeq)

    print 'Sequence Length:', SeqLength

    BaseKey = list(set(DNASeq)) #creates a list from the unique characters in the DNASeq

    Dict = {}

    for char in BaseKey:
        Dict[char] = DNASeq.count(char)
    print Dict
```